# reversing an array using pointer c

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, pointers, reverse

I am trying to write a code that receives the number of input numbers and integers, then reverses those order and prints them out. When I run this code it freezes from the for loop in input_integer function. What am I doing wrong?

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

void input_integer (int *arr, int *arrSize);
void inverse_reorder (int *arr, int *arrSize);

int main (void){
    int* arrSize;
    int* arr;
    int i;

    input_integer(arr, arrSize);
    printf("inputted data : ");
    for ( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i));
    }
    inverse_reorder(arr, arrSize);
    printf("reversed data : ");
    for ( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}

void input_integer (int* arr, int *arrSize){
    printf("Array size = ? ");
    scanf("%d", arrSize);
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        scanf("%d", *(arr + i));
    }   
}

void inverse_reorder (int * arr, int *arrSize){
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        temp = *(arr+i);
        *(arr+i) = *(arr + *arrSize - i);
        *(arr + *arrSize - i) = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your compiler settings: I am pretty sure you should get some warning from `scanf("%d", *(arr + i));`.

Comment: Debugger.................

Answer (score 1):

The `%d` format specifier in `scanf` expects an `int*` as its parameter. However, you are dereferencing the pointer when you do this: `*(arr + i)`. You don't need the `*`.

However, in your `main` function, you declare two pointers that don't point anywhere. You need to allocate some storage e.g.

```
int main (void){
    int arrSize;
    int i;

    int* arr = input_integer(&arrSize);
```

I changed `input_integer` to return the int pointer of the array.

And `input_integer` will allocate storage based on the input array size:

```
int* input_integer (int *arrSize){
    printf("Array size = ? ");
    scanf("%d", arrSize);
    // Should really validate the size here
    int *arr = calloc(*arrSize, sizof *arr); 
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        scanf("%d", arr + i);
    } 
    return arr;  
}
```

Then your main function should always use arrSize without dereferencing it and also free the pointer at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `arrSize` as an `int *`, but you never assign a value to that pointer, so it's value is indeterminate.  When you later pass the value of that pointer to `scanf`, it reads that garbage value and attempts to write to that invalid address.  This invokes undefined behavior.  You also never allocate space for `arr`.  Also, when you read in each array element, you're passing in an array value instead of the address of an array element.

You should declare `arrSize` as an `int` in your `main` function, then pass its address to `input_integer` to populate it.  Then in input_integer, you need use `malloc` to allocate space for the array.  You'll also need to pass in the address of `arr` to write to it.

```
int main (void){
    int arrSize;
    int *arr;
    int i;

    input_integer(&arr, &arrSize);
    printf("inputted data : ");
    for ( i = 0; i < arrSize ; i++ ){
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i));
    }
    inverse_reorder(arr, arrSize);
    printf("reversed data : ");
    for ( i = 0; i < arrSize ; i++ ){
        printf("%d, ", *(arr + i));
    }

    return 0;
}

void input_integer (int **arr, int *arrSize){
    printf("Array size = ? ");
    scanf("%d", arrSize);
    *arr = malloc(*arrSize * sizeof(int));
    if (*arr == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i;
    for( i = 0; i < *arrSize ; i++ ){
        scanf("%d", *arr + i);
    }   
}

void inverse_reorder (int *arr, int arrSize){
    int i;
    int temp = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < arrSize ; i++ ){
        temp = *(arr+i);
        *(arr+i) = *(arr + arrSize - i);
        *(arr + arrSize - i) = temp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

arrSize is not a pointer it should be a value for the program to run.
You can't compare the incremented i in the loop to the reference value of arrSize otherwise it will be looping for long and long as the loop's limit would be the pointer address.
You should access the pointers only when writing , never on reading (unless it's intended).

Answer (score 0):

Variables `arrSize` and `arr` are not initialized and have indeterminate values

```
int* arrSize;
int* arr;
```

However inside for example the function `input_integer`  their indeterminate values are used.

As result the program in whole has undefined behavior.

There is no need to declare the variable `arrSize` as a pointer.

The variable `arr` must be passed to the function `input_integer` by reference. Otherwise the function will deal with a copy of the value of the variable and the original value of the variable will not be changed.

So the function should be declared at least like

```
void input_integer (int **arr, int *arrSize);
                        ^^^^^
```

The function `inverse_reorder`  in fact does not reverse the order of the elements of the array. That is it reverse the order twice keeping the original order as the result.

You need also to free the allocated array.

The program and the functions can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_integer( int **a, size_t *n );
void inverse_reorder( int *a, size_t n );

int main(void) 
{
    int *a;
    size_t n;

    input_integer( &a, &n );

    if ( n )
    {
        printf( "inputted data : " );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d, ", *( a + i ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        inverse_reorder( a, n );

        printf( "reversed data : " );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n ; i++ )
        {
            printf( "%d, ", *( a + i ) );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );

        free( a );
    }

    return 0;
}

void input_integer( int **a, size_t *n )
{
    *a = NULL;
    *n = 0;

    printf( "Array size = ? " );

    if ( scanf( "%zu", n ) == 1 && *n != 0 )
    {
        *a = malloc( *n * sizeof( int ) );

        printf( "enter %zu integers: ", *n );
        for ( size_t i = 0; i < *n; i++ ) scanf( "%d", *a + i );
    }
}

void inverse_reorder( int *a, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        int tmp = *( a + i );
        *( a + i ) = *( a + n - i - 1 );
        *( a + n - i - 1 ) = tmp;
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
Array size = ? 10
enter 10 integers: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
inputted data : 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
reversed data : 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0,
```

You may add a check that the memory was allocated successfully by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use gcc -Wall to compile your programs.

```
reversing.c: In function ‘input_integer’:
reversing.c:31:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d", *(arr + i));
            ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~
reversing.c: In function ‘main’:
reversing.c:12:3: warning: ‘arr’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
   input_integer(arr, arrSize);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
reversing.c:12:3: warning: ‘arrSize’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
```